# Why use C++'s auto type and then add the return type after ->?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just reading through [Bartek's blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/optional-examples-wall.html) when I found this example:

```
auto to_int( char const * const text ) -> std::optional<int>
{
    char * pos = nullptr;
    const int value = std::strtol( text, &pos, 0 );

    return pos == text ? std::nullopt : std::optional<int>( value );
}
```

Why did they use the idiom `auto to_int( char const * const text ) -> std::optional<int>`?

Isn't this the same as the traditional `std::optional<int> to_int( char const * const text )`?

Is there a reason to prefer one or the other in certain situations? If so, what would these situations be?

**NOT DUPLICATE**

This question is **not** the same as the one [Vittorio Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598696/vittorio-romeo) presented as justification for closing it. I'm not asking for an opinion. I'm asking technically why this idiom was used - it is a valid question.

Comment: I have no idea why they chose to use the trailing return type here.  There is no need for it and they don't use it for most of the code.  You only need a trailing return type when you need to reference the function parameters in the return type.

Comment: Thank you @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica. That makes sense. I thought of decltype and so on, I just wanted to know if in this case there ws a specific reason.

Comment: You don't even need it as of C++14.

Comment: You ask "Is there a reason to prefer one or the other in certain situations? If so, what would these situations be?"  , and the duplicate addresses the question "However, should this new style be preferred everywhere in new C++11-programs, or will it only be used when needed?"   . Seems like the same question to me

Comment: If you want to know why a specific person used some idiom in a specific instance, then asking that person would be the way to go. Otherwise you are just asking for speculation .